# Linear algebra: proving these vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, vectors

> Given $v_1 = (1, 0, 1, 2)^T$, $v_2 = (0, 1, 1, 0)^T$, $v_3 = (−1, 2,
>  1, 0)^T$, $v_4 = (0, 0, 1, 0)^T$.
>
> Prove that $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^4$.

I have no idea because I thought basis are pivot columns like $(1, 0, 0, 0,)$ and $(0, 1, 0, 0)$, but the above are not pivot columns.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ n$ vectors in $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$  are linearly independent if and only if the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Alternative_method_using_determinants) of the matrix formed by taking the vectors as its columns is non-zero.  In this case, it is rather easy to calculate that that determinant is $-2$ (not $0$), so the $4$ vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you , i also got -2 as the answer

Answer (score 2):

What you thought is not correct ! For example $(-3,1)$ and $(0,6)$ form a basis of $ \mathbb R^2.$

You only have to show that $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it  is, put the vectors as the rows of a matrix.  Row-reduce and count the number of pivot columns.  If there are four, you have a basis.

Comment: http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/lindep/lindep.html

Comment: this website takes vectors as columns instead of rows. But i think both methods are correct, is it?

Comment: since the two matrixs obtained by rows and columns are tranpose of each other, they have same determinant

Comment: Right.  And the same rank.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively you can see that as below:

$v_4$ is in the form you like, i.e. it takes care of $e_3$ canonical vector

Now just project ignore this coordinate (i.e. subtract an ad hoc amount of $v_4$)

You are left with $v_1\to(1,0,0,2),v_2\to(0,1,0,0),v_3\to(-1,2,0,0)$ and see that $v_2$ takes care of $e_2$.

Project again $v_1\to(1,0,0,2),v_3\to(-1,0,0,0)$ and $v_3$ takes care of $e_1$.

Last project gives $v_1\to(0,0,0,2)$ which completes the base taking care of $e_4$.

---

You can prove this more seriously by showing the four vectors are independent:

$av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dv_4=(a-c,b+2c,a+b+c+d,2a)=(0,0,0,0)$ and show that $a=b=c=d=0$.

Comment: Thanks..........